# Semantic-UI-React: Form.Field is breaking layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm working on a form to create a new product and I need a row with 3 equals fields but I'm not getting there using React Semantic Ui.

How can I code 3 equal input fields using react semantic ui?

That's what I've tried:

```
import { Form, Input, Button, TextArea, Header, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";

function CreateProduct() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header as="h2" block>
        <Icon name="add square" color="violet" />
        Cadastrar Produto
      </Header>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            name="name"
            label="Nome"
            placeholder="Nome do Produto"
          />
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            name="price"
            label="Preço"
            placeholder="Preço"
            min="0.00"
            step="0.10"
            type="number"
          />
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            name="media"
            type="file"
            label="Imagem"
            accept="image/*"
            content="Escolha Imagem"
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Field
          control={TextArea}
          name="description"
          label="Descrição"
          placeholder="Descrição do Produto"
        />
        <Form.Field
          control={Button}
          inverted
          color="violet"
          icon="pencil alternate"
          content="Cadastrar"
          type="submit"
        />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreateProduct;
```

The output that I am getting is:

[image: Output view]

See the 3rd input "Imagem"?

It seems that the field is not following the Form.Group props widths='equal' from [semanctic-react-ui document](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/)

Answer (score 0):

This layout is exceed because of the `file` type content.
May be you can try this way to get that layout

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button, TextArea } from "semantic-ui-react";

class FormExample extends Component {
  fileInputRef = React.createRef();
  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            name="name"
            label="Nome"
            placeholder="Nome do Produto"
          />
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            name="price"
            label="Preço"
            placeholder="Preço"
            min="0.00"
            step="0.10"
            type="number"
          />
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Imagem</label>
            <Button
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              content="Choose File"
              labelPosition="left"
              icon="file"
              onClick={() => this.fileInputRef.current.click()}
            />
            <input
              ref={this.fileInputRef}
              type="file"
              hidden
              onChange={this.fileChange}
            />
          </Form.Field>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Field
          control={TextArea}
          name="description"
          label="Descrição"
          placeholder="Descrição do Produto"
        />
        <Form.Field
          control={Button}
          inverted
          color="violet"
          icon="pencil alternate"
          content="Cadastrar"
          type="submit"
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormExample;
```

**demo** : https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-frost-9ihqw (adjust the screen size for full view)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I found a solution adding the fluid props on the Form.Field. Works fine now!

Comment: Okay @sydbhat. `fluid` props didn't work for me when I have my input type `file`. If it is works for you, that is really good.

Comment: It didn't work on the image input file either, @danielprabhakaran-n . But I manage to get the same results putting fluid on the price input file. But you've showed me another good way that I'll use in the future. If I had enough reputation I would answer that it was useful, but I cant do that haha!

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution just adding the "Fluid" props on the second .

```
<Form.Field
  fluid
  control={Input}
  name="price"
  label="Preço"
  placeholder="Preço"
  min="0.00"
  step="0.10"
  type="number"
/>
```